# Best database option for PhoneGap applications?

Tags: cordova, local-storage, phonegap-plugins, web-sql

I am looking for an evolved, stable and proven database solution for PhoneGap applications, which is not limited in size.

I have been working with LocalStorage for over a year, and it works quite well. At least if you don't hit the 5 MB limit.

And that's my concern: the app I am currently planning will have to handle much more data, and I don't want to say "Sorry, we reached the 5 MB limit and cannot complete your action!" to a user, who just bought an 64 GB iPhone.

Are there any recommendations?

Thanks!

Thomas

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answer to this question would be using SQLite Database. See the links below -

[SQLite Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118757/max-size-of-websql-sqlite-database-inside-uiwebview-phonegap)

[SQLiteDatabase PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987238/sqlite-database-on-phonegap-ios-more-than-5mb-possible)

Hope it helps.