# where to keep the database in a phonegap application

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, image, cordova

I am new to the Phone gap domain.i have done a small application in android.i just thought of implementing it in Phone Gap and see how it works?

I have used a static database in my android project.i want to use the same for the Phone Gap project?

My big Doubt is where will we keep this Database and how will we access them?

for example..in android we create a Db methods...and store what we want in an array list? and then access them when we want?
for example

```
instance name = db.arraylistname(id);
column name =  instance name.get(0).get("column name");
```

other doubt is about images.what resolution images(hdpi/mdpi/ldpi/xhdpi) should we use in the www/img/ folder?

which language is better to use in Phone Gap Jquery or java script?

Comment: jQuery is a javascript framerwork. In that scenario both the same.

Comment: if you have found this question useful, please Vote UP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used jQuery + jQuery mobile, and they've worked charmingly. jQuery mobile even has some documentation about using phonegap, which can be found at http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/faq/how-configure-phonegap-cordova.php. I've only used ajax to access external databases, so I can't personally offer any advice on local storage, but this question on SO has a marked answer so it looks like it worked for them: [Best database option for PhoneGap applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030076/best-database-option-for-phonegap-applications)

Let me know if you have any questions or want me to clarify anything regarding jQuery Mobile.

Comment: asifrc,thank you.but,i would be happy if anyone can suggest me a way to access the static Database and in which folder should i have it?