# How can I store more than 5MB data on a Phonegap HTML5 offline application?

Tags: database, html, cordova, local-storage

I am working on an HTML5 application. This app must store data (lots of JSON & Base64 pictures) until the user synchronises it with our server. I must keep data stored on the device for a month after a sync.

I will use Phonegap for building the app. I know there is a limit of 5MB, so I'll certainly have to store my data in a different way. What are the best solutions? What would you recommend me?

### Edit:

I forgot to say, but I will have physically all the devices used by my company for installing the application, so maybe there is a way to overpass the restriction by tricking the Android pad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That stands for localStorage and the built in SQLite database. I would suggest you taking a look at the [File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File), which would allow you to store files in the device.

Comment: This sounds old for an offline HTML5 application.
Isn't it possible to install a SQLlite or something ?

Comment: Old? The File API is a HTML5 feature, as the WebSQL Database, which has a limit of 5mb. If you wanted to use a native SQLite DB, you'd have to use a PhoneGap plugin, having in account that you'd need a different one for each device (Android, iOS, etc.). Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118757/max-size-of-websql-sqlite-database-inside-uiwebview-phonegap

Comment: "Sounds old"? What is that even supposed to mean?

Answer (score 2):

There's a neat SQLite plugin [here](https://github.com/chbrody/Cordova-SQLitePlugin) I'm using in an iOS/Android Phonegap application.  I've tested it and found it's methods to work well on both platforms.

As for syncing JSON data and Base64 images, I'm doing this same thing with a SQLite DB managed through this plugin.  I only have a couple hundred smaller images I'm working with but I've found the SQLite DB to be pretty reliable for this purpose.

Thanks to the authors of that plugin.