# Cordova window.openDatabase() on Xcode - no error output

Tags: xcode, cordova

I have a Cordova iOS app that makes a call to `window.openDatabase()` in the `onDeviceReady()` event handler. It seems execution of the `onDeviceReady()` event handler stops on that line, because my `console.log()` beneath that line never show up in the debug console in Xcode. Neither do any other error messages.

The same code works fine on Android devices and `Chrome/Ripple` emulator. What is wrong?

```
var db = null;

// PhoneGap is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("onDeviceReady");

    db = window.openDatabase("mydb", "1.0", "My DB", 100000000);        

    console.log("This will never be displayed in Xcode log");

    db.transaction(checkDB, checkErrorCB);        
}
```

Cordova version: 2.3.0

Xcode version: 4.5.2

I am testing on iPhone 5.1 and iPhone 6.0 simulator.

Comment: the WebKit DB in IOS is limited to 5 Mb, for more info read this answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118757/max-size-of-websql-sqlite-database-inside-uiwebview-phonegap

Answer (score 2):

Doh!!

Seems the DB size I specified was to big, it all started working when I removed a zero... That's the kind of thing that's easy to overlook when you've been looking at the same code for weeks and it's been working fine. I just picked a random large number "to be on the safe side".

This code is working:

```
db = window.openDatabase("mydb", "1.0", "My DB", 10000000);
```